# Is $(\mathbb R^2,+,\cdot )$ a field where $(a,b)\cdot (c,d)=(ac-bd, ad+bc)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $(\mathbb R^2,+,\cdot )$ a field where $(a,b)\cdot (c,d)=(ac-bd, ad+bc)$ ?

I think it is because $\varphi :\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb C$ defined by $\varphi (a,b)=a+ib$ is a ring isomorphism, but my teacher says it's not, and I don't understand why. Any idea ?

Comment: It is a field, since $-1$ is not a square in $\Bbb R$ (which is needed for the existence of a multiplicative inverse).

Comment: I think you are correct. One can check that $\varphi$ is both an additive and multiplicative group homomorphism. Further, the identity of $\mathbb R^2$ (as defined) is $(1, 0),$ and that maps to the identity of $\mathbb C$ under $\varphi,$ so $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism.

Comment: The question is what the teacher really said.

Comment: This is completely answered by https://math.stackexchange.com/a/250770/29335

Comment: Yes, and this is one possible way to define $\mathbb{C}$ (with defining $i=(0,1)$ and $1=(1,0)$, and writing $a+bi$ instead of $(a,b)$).

Comment: You are right: That mapping is a ring isomorphism, and a field isomorphism. $\qquad$

Answer (score -1):

To check if it is a field, let's check the requirements for a field: closure with respect to addition, closure with respect to multiplication, additive identity, multiplicative identity, additive commutativity, additive associativity, multiplicative commutativity, multiplicative associativity, additive inverse, and multiplicative inverse.

Our potential field is defined as $(a,b)$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.  Our addition operation is defined as $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$.  Our multiplication operation is defined as $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$.

The sum and product of real numbers are real numbers, so we have closure with respect to both addition and multiplication.

The additive identity is $(0,0)$.

The multiplicative identity is $(1,0)$.

$$(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)=(c,d)+(a,b)$$
$$((a,b)+(c,d))+(e,f)=(a+c,b+d)+(e,f)=(a+c+e,b+d+f)=(a,b)+(c+e,d+f)=(a,b)+((c,d)+(e,f))$$
$$(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)=(c,d)\cdot(a,b)$$
$$((a,b)\cdot(c,d))\cdot(e,f)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)\cdot(e,f)=(ace-bde-adf-bcf,acf-bdf+ade+bce)=(a,b)\cdot(ce-df,cf+de)=(a,b)\cdot((c,d)\cdot(e,f))$$

Additive inverse of $(a,b)$ is $(-a,-b)$.

Multiplicative inverse of $(a,b)\neq(0,0)$ is $(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2},\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2})$.

This meets all the criteria for a field, so it is a field

Comment: The multiplicative identity is $(1, 0)$ no? And hence the multiplicative inverse is $(a^2 + b^2)^{-1} (a, -b)$?

Comment: @paulinho: Correct.  Fixed